# Making a div out of margin

Tags: html, css-float, margin

### Explanation

I am preparing a webpage with mostly `html` and a few of `javascript` statements. There are many `divs` and I have set a left margin of `100px`. I need to set a `div` at extreme left of my screen but unfortunately it would shake whole of the other objects on the page.

I came out with the idea to place that `div` at the space left by the margin. Is there a way to place the `div` out of the `leftmargin`?

### Example Code

```
<body leftmargin = "100">
<div id="Example1"> </div>
<div id="........"> </div>
</body>
```

This is just an example. If the `leftmargin` is 100 pixels, how to place a new `div` in that space i.e. with `width` 100 pixels?

It can surely exceed `rightmargin` but it starts only after 100 pixels from the left. How to start the `div` from 0 pixels even when there is a 100px margin?

Comment: Learn about floats and positioning

Comment: What is `leftmargin` attribute? Add working fiddle please.

Comment: Guys, stop with the down votes, he/she is just 14 year old, have explained and also contributed the code, we all start from somewhere, so don't downvote without any reason and if you do so provide one

Comment: hi @kashish explain your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: you can make your div `display: fixed;`, thus taking it out of the normal layout and give it width according to your left margin say `width: 100px;` and `left: 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a negative margin, maybe :)

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zVK74/)

HTML

```
<div>This is inside the normal margin</div>
<div id="outside">I defy margins!</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#outside {
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

or maybe `position: absolute;`

[Have a second fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zVK74/1/)

HTML

```
<div>This is inside the normal margin</div>
<div id="outside">I defy margins!</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#outside {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It gave me an idea how to proceed next!

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/82Nvq/)

```
<body class="leftmargin">
<div id="Example1"> </div>
<div id="Example2"> </div>
</body>
```

and css

```
#Example1{
  height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color:#222;   
}
#Example2{
  height:100px;
    width:100px;
 background-color:#333;   
    margin-left:-100px
}
.leftmargin{
    margin-left:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

just set margin-left:-100px

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed! But @misterManSam's answer explained your thing!

Answer (score 1):

The margin is not usually a place where you would put other objects. If you give your body - Element a margin-left of 100px then all elements inside your body will have 100px distance from the left side of the screen. Here's an example how you could have elements on the left and others with 100px distance:

```
<body>
  <div> This div is on the left </div>
  <div style="margin-left:100px"> This div has a 100px margin </div>
</body
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use inline CSS.

```
<body>
<div id="Example1" style="margin-left:100px">this is the first container</div>
<div id="........">this is the 2nd container</div>
</body>
```

[view fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugTdG/)

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

### HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="main">Main content</div>
<div id="left">Left content</div>
</body>
```

### CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

But, I suggest you not to style `body` too much. You should instead use `div` tag.